# Как удалить все партиции старше заданной даты?

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

Есть таблица, основанная на ежедневных партициях.

Можно удалить раздел с помощью следующего запроса:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE ('24-OCT-2021','dd-MON-yyy'))
```

А как можно удалить все партиции (несколько партициий) старше 7 дней?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Drop multiple partitions based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48089186) от участника [@TomJava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8393315/tomjava)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48089186

Answer (score 2):

С клаузой `DROP PARTITION` удалить несколько партиций нельзя ([см. *drop_table_partition*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877__I2131064)).

Можно написать процедуру, которая определит партиции для удаления и удалит их в цикле:

```
create or replace procedure dropPartitions (tableName varchar2, daysOlder int) is 
    deleteOlder constant date := trunc (sysdate) - daysOlder;
    dataDate date; 
begin
    for r in (  select partition_name, high_value 
                from user_tab_partitions
                where table_name = upper (tableName)) loop
        execute immediate 'begin :1 := '||r.high_value||'-1; end;' using out dataDate;
        if dataDate <= deleteOlder and r.partition_name like 'SYS%' then
            execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||tableName||' DROP PARTITION '||r.partition_name;
            dbms_output.put_line (' '||r.partition_name||' for '||dataDate||' droped.');
        end if;    
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Тестовые данные и вызов (сег. 01.10, ожидаю, что будут удалены партиции старше 25.09):

```
create table t (
    id number primary key, created date)
partition by range (created) interval (numToDSInterval (1, 'day')) (
    partition def_part values less than (date'2000-01-01'))
/
insert into t
    select rownum, date'2021-10-01'-(rownum-1)/12
    from dual connect by level<=96;

exec dropPartitions ('t', 7) 

SYS_P11045 for 2021-09-24 00:00:00 droped.
SYS_P11046 for 2021-09-23 00:00:00 droped.
```

---

PS: из оригинального ответа убран блок исключений, потому что он служит для удаления партиции по умоолчанию (первой), которая обычно служит для сбора ошибочных или экзотических записей. Эта партиция не может быть удалена для интервал партиционирования. Если всё таки возникнет потребность, то ее можно удалить вручную временно отключив интервал партиционирование:

```
alter table t set interval ()
/
alter table t drop partition def_part;
/
alter table t set interval (interval '1' day);
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089939) от участника [@Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit)</sub>